# Get Vue.js instance-specific component data within x-template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

One of my root Vue.js components is using an x-template, displayed in 3 different parts of my app (3 separate Vue instances).

Everything is working if I put the data directly into the component, but I can’t figure out how to pass in data to each individual vm instance. Here’s what I’m using at present:

```
Vue.component('some-table', {
    template: '#some-template',
    data() {
        return { someArray: [] }
    },
    methods: {
    }
});

let someVm = new Vue({
    el: '#some-div',
});
```

The template:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-template">
    <table v-for="(item, id) in someArray" v-bind:key="id">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.someKey}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

Within another JavaScript class, I’m attempting to push data to someArray:

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    someMethod() {
        let newData = [1,2,3];
        someVm.someArray = newData;  // doesn't work
        someVm.someArray.push(...newData);  // doesn't work
        someVm.someArray.concat(newData);  // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Using any of the various lines in someMethod() above, I can see someVm contains someArray, but with no observers.

I can’t seem to figure out how to push new data to each instance, then be accessible within some-template. I’m obviously missing something really simple, but I’ve been stuck on this for a while now, so any pointers would be amazing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `data` attr at component registration (`Vue.component(...)`). Instead, declare the props that component uses and pass it through `markup` or `js`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

Vue.component('some-component', {
  template: '#some-component',
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String, // declare the props: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props
    }
  }
});

const cp1 = new Vue({
  el: '#cp1',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "using data"
    };
  }
});

const cp2 = new Vue({
  el: '#cp2'
});

const cp3 = new Vue({
  el: '#cp3'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script id="some-component" type="text/x-template">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
</script>

<div id="cp1">
  <some-component :message="msg"></some-component>
</div>

<div id="cp2">
  <some-component message="using props"></some-component>
</div>

<div id="cp3" is="some-component" message="using props and is"></div>
```